# Harris chain converges to true probability

Tags: markov-chains, law-of-large-numbers

It is well-known that if a Harris chain $\Phi$ has an invariant probability $\pi$, then we have law of large number, i.e.
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac1n \sum_{t=1}^n f(\Phi_t)={\rm E}_{\pi}[f(\Phi_0)], ~ a.s.~ {\rm P}
$$
for each $f\in L_1$, and ${\rm P}$ is the true probability.

My question: could we obtain a limit in the sense of ${\rm E}_{{\color{red} {\rm P}}}[f(\Phi_0)]$?

Thank you very much!